# Get rid of horizontal scroll bar on mobile devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm struggling with a horizontal scroll bar. Can't figure out which element causes it's appearance.

Here is a website https://illia108.github.io/monkey/

UPDATE:

This is what I got using @Chiller advice

[image]

UPDATE 2:

`.wrapper { overflow: hidden; }` does the trick. But as I understand it doesn't remove the root cause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the circle in about section are not responsive. You need to decrease the width of those according to the media.

That is why horizontal scroll is there.

For mobile screens. you can show one circle section per row.

Comment: I've temporarily removed the whole #about section. Still have the horizontal scroll. Am I missing something?

Comment: I pushed an index.html without #about section. Please have a look at the modified website version

Comment: Thank you very much. Now you can see after removing the about section your site is bit responsive now the problem is with the navbar.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I realized what was my actual problem. I had a number of unresponsive elements. Fixing them one by one I removed a horizontal scroller.

From the beginning, I was sure that I have a problem with just one style. It was absolutely mistaken.

Comment: @IlliaKuzma Great! you found your solution